# Accessing variable inside WebSQL Function

Tags: javascript, web-sql

I am using the following code

```
var Year12=new Array();

GetYear(function(Year12) 
{
alert(Year12);
});

   function GetYear(callback) 
     {

       var selectAllStatement = "SELECT DISTINCT year FROM mytable";
       var db = openDatabase("Postit", "1.0", "Notebook", 200000);
       var dataset;
       alert("1");
       db.transaction(function(tx) {
       alert("2");

           tx.executeSql(selectAllStatement, [], function(tx, result) 
           {
           alert("3");
          dataset = result.rows;

          for (var i = 0, item = null; i < dataset.length; i++)
           {

                 item = dataset.item(i);
                 Year12[i]=item['year'];

           }
          callback(Year12);
       });
     });
    }
```

Here the  tx.executeSql statements are not getting executed means alert 3 is not displaying.Is there any way to do this

Answer (score 2):

The `db.transaction` and `tx.executeSql` calls are asynchronous, hence the callback functions. That means that `GetYear` will finish executing and return *before* the `tx.executeSql` callback will populate your `Year12` array.

Once you have asynchronous behavior and callbacks, the only sensible solution is, of course, more callbacks. You need a structure more like this:

```
function GetYear(callback) {
    //...
    db.transaction(function(tx) {
        //...
        tx.executeSql(selectuniqueyearStatement, [], function(tx, result) {
            var Year12 = [ ];
            //... populate the locale Year12 using result.rows
            callback(Year12);
        });
    });
}
```

and then use it like this:

```
GetYear(function(year12) {
    // Do whatever you need to do with the year12 array...
});
```

Basically the same code structure and strategies that you use with AJAX calls.

Comment: hi.. Its not working. when iam calling GetYear(function(year12) {  });, db.transaction is not getting executed the code written outside db.transaction is executed

Comment: @VijeshP: What does the new version look like? You can edit the question to add the new version.